# Address of minimum value in an array in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, minimum

Just a week into `C/C++`. I have a function that takes a pointer to an array as an argument. Manipulating this input array inside the function results in a change in another (globally defined) array. 
I need to find and return the address of the minimum value in this (globally defined) array of floats. In C++ I can do this relatively easily with `std::min_element()`, since this returns an iterator. Any way to do this in C? I can write a loop to find the minimum value in an array, but not sure how to access its address? Here'e the (pseduo)code.

```
globalArray[100] = {0}
float *DoSomething(float *array)
{
    if (conditionMet == 1)
        { Do something to array that modifies globalArray;}
    float min;
    min = globalArray[0];
    for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
    {
         if (globalArray[i] < min)
            min = globalArray[i];
    }
    return &min;
}
```

Comment: post your current code so we can help u.

Comment: Without some code it is hard to tell what you are asking, but isn't it just `return &array[minIndex];` ?

Comment: A week into two different languages at once? Wow. Personally, I'd pick one.

Comment: C and C++, despite their superficial similarities, are very, very different languages. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: Totally understand that C and C++ are different. As I said, I have some sense for how to accomplish this in C++ using std::min_element. But also need to do this in C.

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep an extra variable around to track the index.

```
min = globalArray[0];
int minIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
{
     if (globalArray[i] < min) {
        min = globalArray[i];
        minIndex = i;
     }
}
return &globalArray[minIndex];
```

Alternatively, you can use the extra variable to track the pointer.

```
min = globalArray[0];
float* minPointer = globalArray;
for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
{
     if (globalArray[i] < min) {
        min = globalArray[i];
        minPointer = globalArray + i;
     }
}
return minPointer;
```